# Dask Dataframe groupby results in a pandas series, how do I return a dask dataframe instead?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, dask

I am trying to perform a groupby function in Dask to create a new Dask dataframe.  However, when I do the groupby the result is a pandas series.  When I do the equivalent in Pandas, I do return a new dataframe.  How do I return a new dask dataframe?

Here is the code:

```
 g1 = df1.groupby(['SFDC_Refresh_Date', 'Forecast_Category']).Total.sum().compute()

 g1.dtypes
```

Returns:

```
 dtype('float64')
```

And

```
 type(g1)
```

Returns

```
 pandas.core.series.Series
```

When I do the similar in Pandas

```
 g1 = df.groupby(['SFDC_Refresh_Date', 'Forecast_Category'], as_index=False).Total.sum()
```

And

```
 type(g1)
```

I get

```
 pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

How do I return a Dask dataframe from doing a Dask groupby?

Answer (score 1):

ASFAIK `as_index` is not supported by `dask` see this [issue](https://github.com/dask/dask/pull/807). If you are happy with `reset_index` you can use exactly the same code for `pandas` and `dask`. Here an example of [mcve](/help/mcve)

## Pandas

```py
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
import numpy as np
df =  pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,1,1,1,2,2,2],
                    "b":[1,1,2,2,3,4,4],
                    "Total":[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]})

grp = df.groupby(["a","b"])["Total"].sum()\
        .reset_index()
```

## Dask

```py
df = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)
grp = df.groupby(["a","b"])["Total"].sum()\
        .reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

I got there by doing:

```
 g1 = df1.groupby(['SFDC_Refresh_Date', 'Forecast_Category']).Total.sum().to_frame().compute()
 g2 = g1.reset_index()
 dd_g2 = dd.from_pandas(g2, npartitions=1)
```

Seems roundabout, but it seemed to work

Comment: You could actually skip the `to_frame` method.